# ggplot2 - stacking not well defined when ymin !=0

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting the following data set, I get some strange results and was hoping someone could point out the issue.  I am attempting a facet wrap with my data, but it seems that the results are not truly faceted.

Here is my data set `type.mean.prod.rev`

```
Group.1,            Group.2,           x
Prod1,         Expired,  0.339658789
Prod2,         Expired,  0.450215264
Prod3,         Expired,  0.597100606
Prod4,         Expired,  0.450625850
Prod1,   Expiring In 2013,  0.277917631
Prod2,   Expiring In 2013,  0.122023392
Prod3,   Expiring In 2013,  0.011988620
Prod4,   Expiring In 2013,  0.145343114
Prod1,   Expiring In 2014,  0.386366264
Prod2,   Expiring In 2014,  0.402404085
Prod3,   Expiring In 2014,  0.257194254
Prod4,   Expiring In 2014,  0.396879507
Prod1, Expiring Post 2015, -0.003942683
Prod2, Expiring Post 2015,  0.025357259
Prod3, Expiring Post 2015,  0.133716520
Prod4, Expiring Post 2015,  0.007151529
```

Here is my plotting attempt

```
type.mean.prod.rev.bar <- ggplot(type.mean.prod.rev, 
                             aes(x = type.mean.prod.rev$Group.2,
                                 y = type.mean.prod.rev$x)) + 
  geom_bar(bindwidth = 2,
       stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Group.1, ncol = 4) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill=NA),
    strip.text = element_text(vjust=.7, 
                               colour="white", 
                               face="bold", 
                               size = rel(1.2)),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = rgb(red=25,
                                               green = 187,
                                               blue = 222, 
                                               maxColorValue = 255),
                                    colour = "black",
                                    size = 1)) + ylab(NULL) + xlab(NULL)


type.mean.prod.rev.bar
```

The problem with my output is that each level of `Group.2` is not represented in each panel, but rather each level is in exactly *one* panel, almost as if the facets are purely aesthetics and the data set is still being treated as whole (`Group.1` by `x`).  I know that there is a negative number in `x`, which may cause trouble...  But even when I reset this value to zero with `type.mean.prod.rev[13, 3] <- 0` I get the same results.  Anyone know why the output is off?

Comment: When you're inside `aes` use just the column names rather than the `$`  syntax:  `ggplot(type.mean.prod.rev, aes(x=Group.2, y=x)) + ...`.

Comment: That got it!  Want to post as answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot2 warning: Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481634/ggplot2-warning-stacking-not-well-defined-when-ymin-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're inside `aes` use just the column names rather than the `$`  syntax:  `ggplot(type.mean.prod.rev, aes(x=Group.2, y=x)) + ...`.

Comment: The same principle applies in lattice functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem arises because you are set  the aesthetic as `type.mean.prod.rev$Group.2` instead of `Group2`.

This is confusing `ggplot`.

Other points

- `binwidth` only makes sense if you are using `stat = 'bin'`, to set the width of the `bars` use `width`
- `Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0` is a result of your `negative` value in `x`, which is not really well defined for a bar chart (which begins at `0`) -- floating bar charts aren't covered by `geom_bar`

Because I'm lazy, I've renamed your dataset `DT`

```
# a minimal example (no theme alterations)
ggplot(DT, aes(x = Group.2, y = x)) + 
    geom_bar(width = .2,
             stat = "identity") + 
    coord_flip() +
    facet_wrap( ~ Group.1, ncol = 4)
```